# Mockito - How to avoid inserting data into DB?

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, mockito

How can we write mockito for the below code? It's been written in normal JDBC. I need to create a mock of all this code having main method (which is driving all the logic of updating the data).

I am really need help in mocking the avoid inserting the actual data. Could someone please guide me ?

```
public class PaytPaytmBilling { 
    private static Category logger = Category.getInstance(PaytPaytmBilling.class);
    private static InputStream inputS = XY.class.getResourceAsStream("/paytm.properties");

    private static final INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT STATEMENT";


    private static void insertPaytPaytmBilling(ArrayList allPaytPaytmBill) throws Exception{

        conn = getConnection(userId, passwd, prop.getProperty("databaseURL"));

        String childSql = buildInsertPaytPaytmBillSql();

        PreparedStatement pStatement =  conn.prepareStatement(childSql);

        for (int i=0; i<allPaytPaytmBill.size(); i++){
            PaytPaytmBill PaytmBill = (PaytPaytmBill) allPaytPaytmBill.get(i);

            pStatement.setString(1, PaytmBill.getXX());
            pStatement.setString(2, PaytmBill.getYY());
            pStatement.setString(3, PaytmBill.getAA());
            pStatement.setLong(4, PaytmBill.getBB());
            pStatement.setLong(5, PaytmBill.getCC));            
            pStatement.setString(6, PaytmBill.getDD());
            pStatement.setInt(7, PaytmBill.getEE());
            pStatement.setInt(8, PaytmBill.getFF());
            pStatement.setString(9, "");
            pStatement.setString(10, "");
            pStatement.execute();       
        }   
        pStatement.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    private static void getDbConn() throws Exception {
        // Here get DB connection
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList allPaytPaytmBill = new ArrayList();
        XY.init();
        getDbConn();
        // This query reads data from other tables and creates the data..
        String qmrString = qmr.buildQmrSql();

        allPaytPaytmBill = qmr.getAllMemberData(qmrString);

        insertPaytPaytmBilling(allPaytPaytmBill);
    }   
}
```

Mockito Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PaytmBillingTest {
    private static Category logger = Category.getInstance(PaytmBillingTest.class);

    @Mock
    private DataSource ds;

    @Mock
    private Connection c;

    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement stmt;

    @Mock
    private ResultSet rs;

    private ArrayList<PaytmBill> allPaytmBill;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        allPaytmBill = new ArrayList<>();
        PaytmBill PaytmBill = new PaytmBill();
        PaytmBill.setAA("1182"); 
        PaytmBill.setBB("5122");
        PaytmBill.setCC("201807");
        PaytmBill.setDD(0L);
        PaytmBill.setEE(100);
        PaytmBill.setFF(0);
        PaytmBill.setGG(0);
        PaytmBill.setHH("A");
        PaytmBill.setII(null);
        PaytmBill.setJJ(null);

        allPaytmBill.add(PaytmBill);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPaytmBilling() {    
        PaytmBilling PaytmBilling = new PaytmBilling();

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here? There's no code that warrants a unit test. You also might want to learn how to use generics, they've been around for quite a while after all.

Comment: @Kayaman - Yes sir, I know its very basic. But the code base which I got is legacy (written in 2004-05), the same code I need to work on without upgrading anything. Please let me know what exact need to mock ?

Comment: Given JDBC is rather complex unit testing the class which purpose is to work with DB using JDBC does not make sense. The effort and complexity makes such test not reliable and fragile. It may make sense to test such class using integration test with some in-memory database like H2.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like you are not showing use the real code. For example you added `private static void getDbConn()` but the code calls `conn = getConnection(...)`, the variable `conn` is not declared anywhere, etc. This makes it harder to really help with your issue.

Looking at your unit test, you want to mock instances of certain classes used by PaytPaytmBilling, like DataSource, Connection and PreparedStatement. These are called 'dependencies'.

In order to do that, you need to change PaytPaytmBilling so that these dependencies are 'injected' (see [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)). This means they are provided to PaytPaytmBilling via the constructor or a setter (or with some frameworks just by adding an annotation on the field).

In the current code, the dependencies are obtained by PaytPaytmBilling itself (e.g. by calling a static method, or creating a new instance) and they cannot be mocked (except via some black magic mocking frameworks which I don't advise you to get into right now).

To write good unit tests, you need to write (or refactor) the code to be testable, which means dependencies are injected, not obtained internally in the class. Also avoid static methods and data (constants are ok), they don't play nice with dependency injection and testable code.

So for example the DataSource could be injected via the constructor like this:

```
public class PaytPaytmBilling { 

    private static final String CHILD_SQL = "SELECT bladiebla...";

    private DataSource dataSource;        

    public PaytPaytmBilling(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void insertPaytPaytmBilling(List<PaytmBill> allPaytPaytmBill) {
        // keeping the example simple here.
        // don't use String literals for the parameters below but read 
        // them from Properties (which you can mock for the unit test)
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection("userId", "passwd", "url");
        PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(CHILD_SQL);
        for (int i=0; i<allPaytPaytmBill.size(); i++){
            PaytPaytmBill PaytmBill = (PaytPaytmBill) allPaytPaytmBill.get(i);
            pStatement.setString(1, PaytmBill.getXX());
            pStatement.setString(2, PaytmBill.getYY());
            pStatement.setString(3, PaytmBill.getAA());
            // ...
            pStatement.execute();       
        }               
        pStatement.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

If you re-write the code like above, you could test it like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PaytmBillingTest {

    // this will cause Mockito to automatically create an instance 
    // and inject any mocks needed
    @InjectMocks
    private PaytmBilling instanceUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private DataSource dataSource;

    // connection is not directly injected. It is obtained by calling 
    // the injected dataSource
    @Mock
    private Connection connection;

    // preparedStatement is not directly injected. It is obtained by
    // calling the connection, which was obtained by calling the 
    // injected dataSource
    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    private List<PaytmBill> allPaytmBill;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        allPaytmBill = new ArrayList<>();
        PaytmBill paytmBill = new PaytmBill();
        paytmBill.setAA("1182"); 
        paytmBill.setBB("5122");
        paytmBill.setCC("201807");
        paytmBill.setDD(0L);
        paytmBill.setEE(100);
        paytmBill.setFF(0);
        paytmBill.setGG(0);
        paytmBill.setHH("A");
        paytmBill.setII(null);
        paytmBill.setJJ(null);

        allPaytmBill.add(PaytmBill);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPaytmBilling() {    
        // given
        when(dataSource.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(connection);
        when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(preparedStatement);

        // when
        instanceUnderTest.insertPaytPaytmBilling(allPaytPaytmBill);

       // then
       verify(pStatement).setString(1, paytmBill.getXX());
       verify(pStatement).setString(2, paytmBill.getYY());
       verify(pStatement).setString(3, paytmBill.getAA());
       // ...
       verify(pStatement).execute();
       verify(pStatement).close();
       verify(connection).close();
    }
```

Unrelated suggestion regarding your code: It's better to close resources in a finally block, or using [try-with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). In you current code resources will not be closed if an exception occurs whilst processing on the resources:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection("userId", "passwd", "url");
PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(childSql);
try {
    // processing steps
}
finally {
    pStatement.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Or try-with-resources:

```
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection("userId", "passwd", "url"),
     PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(childSql)) {

    // processing steps
}
```

Since Connection and PreparedStatement implement the [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface they will be closed automatically when the try block ends. This is possible since Java 7.

Comment: minor note: `try-with-resource` exists since java 7

Comment: Right your are!

Comment: I am getting error: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Comment: Can't we mock the Private Static method ?

Comment: If a method is private that indicates it is not meant to be accessible from outside the class. So mocking (or calling) such a method in a unit test does not make sense. Everything is possible if you resort to reflection (or tools that use reflection) but it doesn't result in useful unit tests.

Comment: So how is that private method called in the real application? From the main method? If so, best idea is to first create an instance of PaytPaytmBilling  in the main method, and then call a public method on that instance. That makes the class testable.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster  - All the methods of class (legacy) code uses Private Static and its getting difficult to make this working with Mockito. Could you please suggest the same solution with the EasyMock ?

Comment: If you go down that road it will not add a lot of value. Why do you want this unit test exactly? What problem are you trying to solve with it?